# AWS check user policy document using Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am developing an application in Java and it requires the user to have a policy document. The user enters the access key and secret key. I got AmazonIdentityManagementClient object using the credentials. My application requires "lambda:InvokeFunction". Can any one pls guide me how to check the user policy has lambdainvoke.

Comment: It's not a best practice to give out an AWS access key, secret key to end users of your application. What is the use case that requires this?

Comment: I want to start and stop instances using my application.

Comment: AmazonIdentityManagement iam = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(credentials);

ListAttachedUserPoliciesResult res = iam.listAttachedUserPolicies(req);


is throwing Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AmazonIdentityManagementException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service:AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 041cc807-e888-11e6-87da-1fcd46626f3e)

at listAttachedUserPolicies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AmazonIdentityManagementClient.listAttachedUserPolicies()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagementClient.html#listAttachedUserPolicies-com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.ListAttachedUserPoliciesRequest-) to list the policies attached to a user. This will get you to a list of policy ARNs which you can pass to [AmazonIdentityManagementClient.getPolicy()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagementClient.html#getPolicy-com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.GetPolicyRequest-).

Comment: AmazonIdentityManagement iam = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(credentials);

ListAttachedUserPoliciesResult res = iam.listAttachedUserPolicies(req);

is throwing Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AmazonIdentityManagementException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service:AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 041cc807-e888-11e6-87da-1fcd46626f3e)

at listAttachedUserPolicies

Answer (score 2):

Try below code to get the attached policy as a string.

```
AmazonIdentityManagementAsync iam = AmazonIdentityManagementAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials("",
                                "")))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(""))
                .withClientConfiguration(getClientConfiguration()).build();

        ListAttachedUserPoliciesRequest pre = new ListAttachedUserPoliciesRequest();
        pre.setUserName(iam.getUser().getUser().getUserName());

        ListAttachedUserPoliciesResult re = iam.listAttachedUserPolicies(pre);
        re.getAttachedPolicies().forEach(p -> {
            GetPolicyRequest preq = new GetPolicyRequest();
            preq.setPolicyArn(p.getPolicyArn());
            GetPolicyResult r = iam.getPolicy(preq);
            GetPolicyVersionRequest req = new GetPolicyVersionRequest();
            req.setPolicyArn(p.getPolicyArn());
            req.setVersionId(r.getPolicy().getDefaultVersionId());
            GetPolicyVersionResult res = iam.getPolicyVersion(req);
            System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(res.getPolicyVersion().getDocument()));
        });
```